# in Excel I want trailing 0's on a rounded value that ends up in a text formatted cell, how can I do that?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I am trying to make an excel sheet show a trailing 0 after a decimal place if a value is rounded to a whole number (ie 39.0 is displayed when value is 38.9), however there is a caveat.  It needs to show this in a cell formatted as TEXT and not a number.

I have tried making a NUMBER formatted cell do the calculation and rounding, formatting to add the trailing 0, then have the TEXT cell equal the calculation cell with the trailing 0 but it does not work and the TEXT cell just shows the formula making reference to the calculating cell. (ie the TEXT cell displays "=B4")

If I set the TEXT cell to GENERAL and enter the formula to refer to the calculating NUMBER cell I get the value of the calculation, but without the 0 on the rounded whole number (ie. 39).  I can then change the cell to TEXT but the number stays the same.

I am joining this worksheet to a geodatabase in ESRI's Arcmap and for format/layout reasons the joining fields all have to be data type STRING, meaning I have to force all my joining excel cell formats to be TEXT so they become STRING when Arcmap looks at them.

Is there a way to have a TEXT cell show the exact displayed value of a NUMBER cell without the TEXT cell dropping the NUMBER cell's formatting?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the following, `=TEXT(ROUND(C4/D4,1),"#,##0.0")` where the Round function limits to one decimal place and the Text function includes formatting in the last argument.  If you are dealing in currency, just add a `$` sign like this, `=TEXT(ROUND(C4/D4,1),"$#,##0.0")` or add additional decimal points like this, `=TEXT(ROUND(C4/D4,1),"#,##0.000")`.

If you know the functions you wish to use such as Text, you may type it into the help on Excel (use <kbd>F1</kbd> or search help bar depending on the version of Excel you are using.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest better use the **Ceiling** Function instead of the **Round**.

**=CEILING(K131,1)**

Where 1 is significance of number.

Because Ceiling is technically better and if you use both the Formula on **38.9**, you find **Round will reflect 38.9** but **Ceiling give you 39**. Even **Roundup is also not producing 39.**

Reason is simple Ceiling considers the whole number but Round and Roundup considers number after the decimal.

Now returning to your other issue that is, you need **Trailing Zero** after decimal. To solve the issue you need to select the Cells then click Number Format Tool Button then click Custom format and simply apply this **$#,##0.00**.

I'm not suggesting you to use Text command to format the cell because after that if any where you use that particular cell for calculation, you get #Value error.

Hope this help you I've posted the solution after Commands bee tested by me.